Failure to mount external harddisk in Ubuntu 22.04
Recently I have switched from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 22.04. One of my external hard disks, a Western Digital Elements 3 TB hard disk, which has always mounted properly in 18.04, did mount and worked properly for a few days in 22.04. Then it stopped working because it became impossible to mount it. When using it with another computer under Windows 11, it mounts and works properly.
The error message in Ubuntu 22.04:
Unable to access "Elements". 
Error mounting /dev/sdi1 at /media/lubomir/Elements1: Unknown error when mounting /dev/sdi1

Please help me to resolve this.

Can you do a fs check from disks or gparted?

Was the disk in question last used on a Windows system with the "Fast boot" setting enabled?
The Windows "Fast Boot" (Windows defaults to "ON") setting leaves the disk partition in an undocumented, proprietary state that Linux isn't permitted to recognize. Boot back into Windows and disable "Fast Boot". Be prepared to have to re-disable "Fast Boot"  - Windows updates have been known to turn it back on. See https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup

... see also Ubuntu 20.04 Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/

Does this answer your question? Can't access windows 10 partition after update to 23.10

I thank everybody who responded so far. A solution was found successfully and it is, in a way, a collective solution based on a combination of more than one of the above pieces of advice, as follows.

I post this comment as solution below, because the description was too long and was not accepted as a comment here..

Actually this worked for me.

Check the status of the disks by using : lsblk.
Then use the command : sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1, here replace the /dev/sdb1 drive with your drive name found using the lsblk.

More info from option 1 in this URL:
https://learnubuntumate.weebly.com/fix-82038203error-mounting.html

This works well. Thanks

I thank everybody who responded so far. A solution was found successfully and it is, in a way, a collective solution based on a combination of more than one of the above pieces of advice, as follows. It turns out that this error was known when switching between 18.04 and 20.04 see the above response by steeldriver, and one of the solutions proposed there, worked here, too. Namely, on the terminal I started firs by 'sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdi1' with response 'Error opening '/dev/sdi1': No such file or directory. Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.' This seems to suggest that the above response of waltinator directs towards the cause of the failure -- the harddisk was indeed working for some time in Windows 11 before moved back to Ubuntu 22.04. I did not rush to use chkdsk in Windows 11, however, and instead first ran in the terminal the second recommendation in the link provided by steeldriver: 'sudo apt install --reinstall ntfs-3g'. THIS SOLVED THE PROBLEM without resorting to using chkdsk in Windows.

check for the nfts file system
install nfts using this command: sudo apt install nfts-3g

You did not read the comments with the original question. There is no need to do what you suggest here.

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review

this comment was not super complete but it was helpful to make me realize the usb drive was formatted as ntfs.

I was able to fix it using Disks app -> Repair Filesystem.

